# Blackscreen after boot ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, boot, grub2

I have a dual boot (w7, ubuntu 12.10 ) laptop. Everything was OK since some weeks. Now I am unable to boot my ubuntu 99 times of a hundred.

The process start with the bios settings and all, then grub screen shows up normally ( with all the correct options ) then, when I choose ubuntu option screen turns black ( with back-light )  and that's all ...

I have tried with Ctrl+Alt+F1 to try to drop to the root console but nothing happens ...

IF I try enough times the logging screen shows up and from there everything goes smoothly.

This is my first serious issue with Ubuntu (and I'm using it since 8.04 version ) and I have no idea where to start investigating ...

This error has made my computer unusable so please, I need help ...

Thanks for all in advance.

P.S.:Since I updated to 12.10 while I am working normally from time to time a window pops up with a "System program problem detected". I haven't found a way to get more details about the problem and after reading some web sites seems something "normal" ( or at least common ) but I mention it here just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it seems that the problem is the kernel version.

Last kernel update was 3.5.0-27 and it seems it has some problems with the video drivers of multiple graphic cards.
After reading [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1167114) [two](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1167114) bug reports I thought the kernel could be the problem and try to boot with the 3.5.0-26 ( thanks good that ubuntu stores the last used kernels just in case ), no problem since then. I have been able to boot my laptop 10 times from 10 tries so I think the problem was the kernel.

I do not know what the problem was exactly and the bug reports are not solved yet, so until then I will not update my system to the 3.5.0-27 kernel version.

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the same problem I had, but this solved it for me:

in grub select the ubuntu entry and press e. now look for the words 'quiet splash'. delete them and type 'nomodeset' in stead. now press f10 to boot into ubuntu. I can not tell you what happens or why it works, but for me it did. I got my answer from [here](http://www.ashwinraon.com/2012/08/how-to-solve-ubuntu-blank-screen-boot/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @user146890 . I have tried the nomodeset option, the behaviour has changed, now the power button works ( a short push shutdown the laptop while before I have to long press to switch it off ) but the problem is still there: BlackSreen and no root console wuth Ctrl+Atl+F1 ... still (almost) the same problem.

Comment: @thamurath a pitty the nomodeset option did not work, you could try to reinstall grub, I used [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) program recently, and it helped me trough the process. otherwise I would start thinking of a fresh install, but maybe someone else will come up with a better solution...